# Automatically run unit tests when a file changed, but wait for "app watch" to finish

Tags: windows, unit-testing, events, extjs, sencha-cmd

I managed to set up a headless test environment for Ext6 that automatically runs unit tests related to files that are changed. That works OK so far, but my tests get executed before "sencha app watch" finishes it's thing (rebuild I guess).

To run a test a batch script has to be called, like this: `test.bat -src c:\project\app.js`
That would simply run all tests related to the source file app.js.

So basically I'm looking for a way to set up "app watch" in a way that it calls my batch script when it is done. (and my batch script obviously needs a way to find out which source files changed causing app watch to rebuild)

Comment: Why would you run the tests on every save? I imagine you'll have tests failing all the time -- wouldn't it be a better idea to run the tests on a pre-commit hook?

Comment: The question should be, "why not?". It's not blocking and once I think I should have a look at the tests, I don't have to wait for every single test to finish.